# SQL Server : finding duplicates based on first few characters on column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find duplicates based on the first three characters of the surname, is there a way a to do that on SQL? I can compare the whole name, but how to do we compare the first few characters?

Below are my tables

```
  custid  forename  surname dateofbirth
----------------------------------------
    1       David   John    16-09-1985
    2       David   Jon     16-09-1985
    3       Sarah   Smith   10-08-2015
    4       Peter   Proca   11-06-2011
    5       Peter   Proka   11-06-2011
```

This is my query that I am currently running to compare

```
SELECT
    y.id, y.forename, y.surname
FROM 
    customers y
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         forename, surname, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
     FROM customers
     GROUP BY forename, surname
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dt ON y.forename = dt.forename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use exists as follows:

```
select t.* from t
 Where exists 
      (select 1 from t tt
        Where left(t.surname, 3) =  left(tt.surname, 3) and t.custid <> tt.custid
      ) 
order by t.surname;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by left(surname, 3)) as cnt
      from customers c
     ) c
order by surname;
```

You can include the `forename` as well in the `partition by` if you mean `forename` *and* first three letters of surname.